# EF Adding a new item through interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im new to MVC and EF and in a bit of a tangle i have the following Interface:

```
  public interface IReportDataSource
{
   IQueryable<PostDetail> PostDetails { get; }
   void Save();
}
```

this database context:

```
  public class ReportDb: DbContext, IReportDataSource
{
    public DbSet<PostDetail> PostDetails { get; set; }

    public ReportDb()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    void IReportDataSource.Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();

    }

    IQueryable<PostDetail> IReportDataSource.PostDetails
    {
        get { return PostDetails; }
    }
}
```

and this action

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostDetails(PostDetailsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //save

          //  var storePost = _db.PostDetails.Single();

            var pd = new PostDetail();
            pd.Grade = viewModel.Grade;
            pd.ContractType = viewModel.SelectedContractType;
            pd.Directorate = viewModel.SelectedDirectorate;
            pd.Division = viewModel.Division;
            pd.HoursPerWeek = viewModel.HoursPerWeek;
            pd.Length = viewModel.SelectedContractLength;
            pd.LineManager = viewModel.LineManager;
            pd.LineManagerContactNumber = viewModel.LineManagerContactNumber;
            pd.PositionTitle = viewModel.PositionTitle;
            pd.Section = viewModel.Section;
            pd.SpecifyDuration = viewModel.SpecifyDuration;
            pd.SpecifyEndDate = viewModel.SpecifyEndDate;

            _db.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeController");

        }
```

I think I need to be able to call add through my interface to add the new PostDetails object to the datacontext before calling save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `_db.PostDetails.Add(pd)` before save could help

Comment: Thanks from the examples I have seen that is what I was trying to do, my issue is that I don't get the add method from _db.PostDetails

Comment: DbSet implements more interfaces than IQuery: public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, IDbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IInternalSetAdapter

Comment: You could consider to change IQueryable<PostDetail> to DbSet<PostDetail> in interface IReportDataSource.